Detent in Manipulate slider
I'd like to add a detent on a slider in a Manipulate. Here's an example:
Manipulate[u = If[Abs[u - 0.5] < 0.2, 0.5, u]; u, {u, 0, 1}]
The problem is, as you move the slider in the vicinity of 0.5, the slider graphic jumps around. Can you have the slider graphic based on some other variable, say v? As in the following:
Manipulate[v = If[Abs[u - 0.5] < 0.2, 0.5, u]; v, {u, 0, 1(*,something here to make the slider graphic track with v*)}]

Setting the iterator u to a value in Manipulate is really strange. Why don't you just do Clear[u]; Manipulate[If[Abs[u - 0.5] < 0.2, 0.5, u], {u, 0, 1}]? This also fixes the problem.

The slider in the vicinity of 0.5 jumps back to 0.5 due to "u=..." where you explicitly set it back to 0.5.

Maybe this is what you're after:
Manipulate[u, {u, 0, 1, 
  TrackingFunction -> ((u = If[Abs[# - 0.5] < 0.2, 0.5, #]) &)}]

You cannot really change in the body of Manipulate[] a variable whose control is active. The control will reset the value just as much as the body of Manipulate.

Thanks. I did not find TrackingFunction in the documentation for Manipulate.

@rhomboidRhipper You used to have to use the 2nd argument to Dynamic[] in an explicit call to the control in Manipulate. Then they added the TrackingFunction option to Manipulate control syntax some versions ago. But if you can't find it documented, TrackingFunciton -> tfunc becomes the second argument Dynamic[var, tfunc], and that is documented under Dynamic[].
